# discord.py command with additional arguments/parameters

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make simple command with arguments in discord.py. I want to ensure that by executing a specific command, administrators will be able to authorize themselves with a one-time authorization code generated by their username and individual PIN.

something like:
`mydcbot.auth foo bar`

I'm basing this on this piece of code

```
if msg.startswith("Bondziorno"):
  await message.channel.send("some text with auth code")
  - other things this command does -
```

I also understand that this may not be possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - discord.py on\_message - pass positional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62885708/python-discord-py-on-message-pass-positional-arguments)